# Extracting all routes in a From To data set in R or Python

Tags: python, r, arrays, vector, logic

From this data set of supply chains I am trying to extract each and every route and put all the stages of one specific route in one vector such as this. This is how the from to data is stored.

```
From            To
Manuf_0001      Retail_0001
Manuf_0001      Retail_0002
Manuf_0002      Retail_0003
Manuf_0002      Retail_0001
Part_0001       Manuf_0001
Part_0001       Manuf_0002
Part_0002       Manuf_0001
Part_0002       Manuf_0002
Part_0003       Manuf_0001
Part_0003       Manuf_0002
```

[image: Visual of the supply chain routes]

And this is how I want the vectors of each route to be outputted.

```
Part_0001, Manuf_0001, Retail_0001
Part_0001, Manuf_0001, Retail_0002
Part_0002, Manuf_0001, Retail_0001
Part_0002, Manuf_0002, Retail_0002
Part_0002, Manuf_0002, Retail_0003
Part_0003, Manuf_0001, Retail_0001
Part_0003, Manuf_0002, Retail_0002
Part_0003, Manuf_0002, Retail_0003
```

Comment: Did you create any code?  What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult to completely answer your question because you are not providing code and the details of your problem. 
Nevertheless, I have the feeling that you are looking for something like the [igraph library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) where you can use the *distance()* or *shortest_path()* [functions](https://igraph.org/r/doc/distances.html), notice that you may have to set the **ouptut** argument to get te routes. Check [This nice tutorial](https://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph) (mainly section 7) and [this](https://www.jessesadler.com/post/network-analysis-with-r/)

Another option is the [dodgr library](https://github.com/ATFutures/dodgr)

Answer (score 0):

We can create the desired output as follows.

1. Convert the connections to a graph
2. Find the paths from parts to Retail in the graph

Graph generation code (from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/)

```
from collections import defaultdict 

#This class represents a directed graph  
# using adjacency list representation 

class Graph: 

    def __init__(self,vertices): 
        #No. of vertices 
        self.V= vertices  

        # default dictionary to store graph 
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)  

    # function to add an edge to graph 
    def addEdge(self,u,v): 
        self.graph[u].append(v) 

    '''A recursive function to print all paths from 'u' to 'd'. 
    visited[] keeps track of vertices in current path. 
    path[] stores actual vertices and path_index is current 
    index in path[]'''
    def printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path): 

        # Mark the current node as visited and store in path 
        visited[u]= True
        path.append(u)  # add element of path

        # If current vertex is same as destination, then print 
        # current path[] 
        if u ==d: 
            # Convert path (which are ints) to names
            named_path = [int_to_names[x] for x in path]

            # print names
            print (*named_path, sep = ", ")
        else: 
            # If current vertex is not destination 
            #Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
            for i in self.graph[u]: 
                if visited[i]==False: 
                    self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path) 

        # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited 
        path.pop() 
        visited[u]= False


    # Prints all paths from 's' to 'd' 
    def printAllPaths(self,s, d): 

        # Mark all the vertices as not visited 
        visited =[False]*(self.V) 

        # Create an array to store paths 
        path = [] 

        # Call the recursive helper function to print all paths 
        self.printAllPathsUtil(s, d,visited, path) 

def generate_paths(names_to_int, int_to_names, connections):
  g = Graph(len(names_to_int))
# We loop over all row, column combinations and add edge
# if there is a connection between the two nodes
  for (src, dest) in connections:
    isrc = names_to_int[src]
    idest = names_to_int[dest]
    g.addEdge(isrc, idest)

  for (i, name_src) in int_to_names.items():
    # show row+1, so row numbering prints starting with 1
    if "Part" in name_src:
      for (j, name_dest) in int_to_names.items():
        if "Retail" in name_dest:
          g.printAllPaths(names_to_int[name_src], names_to_int[name_dest])
```

Represent connection as a nested list

```
connections = [
  ["Manuf_0001",      "Retail_0001"],
  ["Manuf_0001",      "Retail_0002"],
  ["Manuf_0002",      "Retail_0003"],
  ["Manuf_0002",      "Retail_0001"],
  ["Part_0001",       "Manuf_0001"],
  ["Part_0001",       "Manuf_0002"],
  ["Part_0002",       "Manuf_0001"],
  ["Part_0002",       "Manuf_0002"],
  ["Part_0003",       "Manuf_0001"],
  ["Part_0003",       "Manuf_0002"]]
```

List of names for Parts, Manufacturers and Retail

```
names = set()
for x in connections:
  names.add(x[0])
  names.add(x[1])
names = list(names)
```

Create mapping from names to int (0 to number of names-1)

```
names_to_int = {value:key for (key, value) in enumerate(names)}
```

Inverse mapping from ints to names

```
int_to_names= {key:value for (key, value) in enumerate(names)}
```

2. Generate paths

   generate_paths(names_to_int, int_to_names, connections)

Output

```
Part_0001, Manuf_0001, Retail_0001
Part_0001, Manuf_0002, Retail_0001
Part_0001, Manuf_0002, Retail_0003
Part_0001, Manuf_0001, Retail_0002
Part_0003, Manuf_0001, Retail_0001
Part_0003, Manuf_0002, Retail_0001
Part_0003, Manuf_0002, Retail_0003
Part_0003, Manuf_0001, Retail_0002
Part_0002, Manuf_0001, Retail_0001
Part_0002, Manuf_0002, Retail_0001
Part_0002, Manuf_0002, Retail_0003
Part_0002, Manuf_0001, Retail_0002
```